# Message signature using RSA

Tags: rsa

in my textbook it is stated, that if we have a message, it's signature using RSA and modulo, we can also sign the inverse of the message.

However, it is not explained why can we do so.

Could someone explain to me the reasoning?

Comment: $$(m^d)^e\equiv m^{ed}\equiv m^{(-1)(-1)ed}\equiv (((m^{-1})^d)^{-1})^e\pmod N$$

Comment: Note that this observation assumes not only we're not hashing the message, but also we're not doing any sort of padding operation. In practice, we *always* pad (and hash) the message before signing...

Comment: Also, this observation can be generalized to "given the textbook RSA signature for $m$, we can compute the textbook RSA signature for $m^k \bmod N$, for any integer $k$" (the original observation is specific to $k = -1$

Answer (score 1):

Let the modulus is $n$, the message $1< m < n$. In your textbook RSA the signature is $$s = m^{d} \bmod n,$$ where the $d$ is the private key.

Let the target signature be $s' = s^{-1} \bmod n$ and $m' = m^{-1}$

Let expand $s' = s^{-1} =  (m^{d})^{-1} = (m^{-1})^{d}$

Therefore $s'$ is the signature of $m'$.

That is one of the many other reasons that we never use textbook RSA in practice. We should you [RSA-PSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_signature_scheme) or [RSA-FDH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_Domain_Hash) for signatures.